# Codeception C3 configuration for coverage using webDriver

Tags: phpunit, codeception

Here's what I did:

Added `c3.php` in root

```
app_code
├── c3.php
└── index.php
```

Included `c3.php` in `index.php`

```
<?php
include 'c3.php';

//some other includes 
?>
```

Enabled coverage in `codeception.yml`

```
coverage:
    enabled: true
    remote: false
    c3_url: http://mylocalenv.mine
```

Webdriver config in `acceptance.yml`

```
config:
      WebDriver:
          url: http://mylocalenv.mine
```

xdebug remote is `on`

```
xdebug.remote_enable => On => On
xdebug.remote_handler => dbgp => dbgp
xdebug.remote_host => localhost => localhost
xdebug.remote_log => /logs/xdebug.log => /logs/xdebug.log
xdebug.remote_mode => req => req
xdebug.remote_port => 9000 => 9000
```

I did the `chmod` for `output`

This is report I get 
[image]

Did I miss anything?